# How to use Voldemort Server from inside JUnit?

Tags: java, maven, junit, voldemort

I'm trying to use Voldemort from inside JUnit in a Maven project. While the following Code compiles, it doesn't execute successfully:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception
{
    // Start Voldemort
    VoldemortConfig config = VoldemortConfig.loadFromEnvironmentVariable();
    VoldemortServer server = new VoldemortServer(config);
    server.start();
}
```

instead, this exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: voldemort.utils.JNAUtils.mlockall(I)I
    at voldemort.utils.JNAUtils.mlockall(Native Method)
    at voldemort.utils.JNAUtils.tryMlockall(JNAUtils.java:51)
    at voldemort.server.VoldemortServer.startInner(VoldemortServer.java:251)
    at voldemort.server.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:62)
    at a.b.c.FunctionalTest.setUp(FunctionalTest.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:35)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ClassLoaderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:103)
    at $Proxy0.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:150)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:69)
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Please don't use that name -- call it "you know who"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note this line in your stacktrace

> at voldemort.utils.JNAUtils.mlockall(Native Method)

This indicates that whatever code is being called, uses some native library through `JNI`. `UnsatisfiedLinkedError` is encountered when the native library cannot be loaded by the JVM at the time of loading the class requesting to load this.

To ensure that the ddl / so files could be loaded by your code, use following java system property,

> -Djava.library.path=/path/to/directory/containing/native/libraries

Alternatively you can add the same directory to `PATH` environmental variable on windows, or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable on Linux.

Check out http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html this page describes how to pass system properties to `maven-surefire-plugin` which is responsible for running the tests in Maven.